# OVH - client denied by server configuration:

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, ovh

I take my Symfony project in my server, but I have one error. When i see on the errors on the server, I get it :

```
[Wed Dec 21 11:44:08 2016] [error] [client 92.140.212.141] [host www.triath-swim.fr] client denied by server configuration: /homez.594/triathswog/www/.htaccess, referer: http://www.triath-swim.fr/
[Wed Dec 21 11:44:08 2016] [error] [client 92.140.212.141] [host www.triath-swim.fr] client denied by server configuration: /homez.594/triathswog/www/.htaccess, referer: http://www.triath-swim.fr/
```

I don't understand.

My site web is : www.triath-swim.fr

in /.htaccess :

```
SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER_7_0
```

in www/.htacess :

```
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 7_0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your vhost config? Is your vhost set to point to the `symfony` web directory? Is your DirectoryIndex set to be app.php?

Comment: First, there seems to be a problem with your virtualhost config. When we go to the link provided, we ends up seeing the directory index. Can you add you virtualhost to you post plz?

Comment: I add a picture of my configuration in OVH. What is the virtualHost ? in OVH server ? or Symphony file ?

Comment: virtualhost is the configuration file for your site, it should be located in `/etc/apache2/site-available/your_site.conf`. Can you also screen what you get when you edit your configuration plz?

Comment: But, on Symfony, I don't have file  : .conf